# fromCharCode equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I was wondering if there is a Ruby equivalent of JavaScript's `fromCharCode` function. What it does is converting Unicode values into characters.

Here an example of its return value in JavaScript:

```
String.fromCharCode(72,69,76,76,79)
#=> HELLO
```

Is there an equivalent for that in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Integer#chr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
72.chr
# => "H"
[72,69,76,76,79].map{|i| i.chr }.join
# => "HELLO"
[72,69,76,76,79].map(&:chr).join
# => "HELLO"
```

**UPDATE**

Without parameters chr only handles 8-bit ASCII characters, you have to pass the parameter [`Encoding::UTF_8`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Encoding.html) to chr to handle Unicode characters.

```
512.chr
RangeError: 512 out of char range
        from (irb):8:in `chr'
        from (irb):8
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

```
512.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
# => "Ȁ"
[512,513].map{|i| i.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)}.join
# => "Ȁȁ"
```

Comment: Without parameters `chr` only handles 8-bit ASCII characters, for integers outside the range (0..255) it will raise a `RangeError`. You have to pass the parameter `Encoding::UTF_8` to `chr` to handle Unicode characters, for example `512.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`.

Comment: @toro2k, Thank you for comment. I updated the  answer with your comment.